# How to share a card in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using flutter to build a mobile application which uses cards to display text and images and some other information.
Following is the image of the card:

[image]

As soon as the user clicks on the 'share' text in the card, the bottom sheet opens and shows Facebook, google and twitter options to be shared.

What I want is to share the question text in the card along with its image to the social media platforms. And also I want it to share this as a link so that when a user clicks on the link it is redirected to this screen in the application.

Following is the code I am using when a user clicks on the Facebook share button:

```
await SocialSharePlugin.shareToFeedFacebook(
        caption: 'Question',
        path: file.path,
        onSuccess: (_) {
          print('FACEBOOK SUCCESS');
          return;
        },
        onCancel: () {
          print('FACEBOOK CANCELLED');
          return;
        },
        onError: (error) {
          print('FACEBOOK ERROR $error');
          return;
        });
```

Here file.path contains the image path which is to be sent. The path is perfectly fine, unfortunately I cannot send you the path.

I tried many share plugins but none of them worked for me. Can someone please help me with this? I really need help in this.

Comment: Is your path a network image? And is the path being generated using dynamic linking? Besides the path, does clicking on the shared link, open your application?

Comment: If you want to open your app via link, you need to enable deep linking in your app, otherwise it will open the link inside a browser. https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/navigation/deep-linking

Comment: @HuthaifaMuayyad yes my path is a network image. no the path is not being generated using dynamic linking. no the application only shares the image and not the link